# How to find min and max zoom scales for offline geodatabase using Android ArcGIS framework?

Tags: android, android-mapview, arcgis

I am stuck in setting `MapView's` min and max scale values, my current scales are

```
MAP_MIN_SCALE = 1000000;
MAP_MAX_SCALE = 1;
```

but these are not works for different `geodatabase`, my `geodatabase` spatial reference is WGS84.

Please help me on this.

Comment: How do you set it? What is not working?

Comment: mMapView.setMinScale(MAP_MIN_SCALE);
mMapView.setMaxScale(MAP_MAX_SCALE); setting this but i want this to be calculated dynamically, it works for one geodatabase but if i change geodatabase its not work for that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely in the Geodatabase structure.  If a Layer in a Geodatabase has a min/max set the `MapView` will honor it.  You should set the min/maxScale levels from a Geodatabase at the layer level.  Use the `setMinScale()` & `setMaxScale()` on the layers from the Geodatabase.  This will allow you to override the min/maxScale property of a layer if it is set.